# How do I compute this contour integral estimate using the triangle inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

If C is the arc of the circle $|z|=1$ that lies in the first quadrant, then $$\left|\int_C \operatorname{Log}(z)dz\right|\leq \frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$

The trick I think is to use the triangle inequality for $|\operatorname{Log}(z)|\leq |\operatorname{Log}|z||+|i\operatorname{Arg}(z)|$, but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: Please learn to use TeX.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber This is only the second question I've asked, I'll use it next time.  Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done. $\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}\newcommand{\Arg}{\operatorname{Arg}}$

\begin{align}
\left| \int_C \operatorname{Log} z\,dz \right| &\le
\max_{z\in C} \left| \Log z \right| \cdot \ell(C) \\
&= \max_{z\in C} \left| \ln|z| + i\Arg z\right| \cdot \ell(C) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align}

(assuming you mean the principal branch of the complex logarithm). Note that $ln|z| = 0$ for $z \in C$ and that $0 \le \Arg z \le \frac{\pi}2$. Also $\ell(C)$ is the *length* of $C$.